# Need help accessing and modifying Shader Graph Vector2 property via script (in Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm building a background layer using a shader graph. And I wanna add a parallax effect. I've already wrote a script to do all the math crap. Now all that's left is to change one of my Shaders "Vector2 properties" at runtime (which will apply the math I've calculated).

Context aside, how do I access and modify

[image: this property]

via script?
(It's a "Vector2" btw)

I found "Material.SetFloat" in the Unity Documentation but I can't seem to find anything for a Vector2?

Answer (score 1):

For all vectors, use the [SetVector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetVector.html) function.

It takes a Vector4 (xyzw), but you should be able to pass it a Vector2.

Use the name of the property as it shows in shader graph under `Reference Name`, which by default starts with an underscore.  eg. `_MyProperty`.

```
myMaterial.SetVector("_MyProperty", myVector2);
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I eventually came up with a work around and just split the Vector2 into 2 separate floats(x,y) before converting them into an Vector2 in the Graph Editor. That way I could use the SetFloat function. Now I feel pretty dumb though. But at least now I know for next time :)